# What's the wrong in this code to find prime factorization

Tags: python, prime-factoring

I tried to find the prime factorization using this code but the program enter an infinite loop.
I tried to figure out what makes the program enter this infinite loop but unfortunately I couldn't.
The code is:

```
N = int(input())
B = N
L = []
while B != 1:
    for i in range(2,N):
        if N % i ==0:
            L.append(i)
            B = N // i
            break
    else:
        L.append(N)
        B = 1
L.pop()
print(L)
```

Comment: the IDE you are using should (hopefully) have a debugger. Like Hammurabi says, you should use the debugger to walk through your code line by line to see what it is exactly doing, and what the variables are at each point, and see where it doesn't do what you want it to do. Knowing how to use your debugger will help a lot

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `break` statement, every time when for loop begins and the condition `if N % i ==0` is reached forces to start a new for loop and this creates an infinity loop. So what you have to do is removing `break`

```
N = int(input())
B = N
L = []
while B != 1:
    for i in range(2,N):
        if N % i ==0:
            L.append(i)
            B = N // i
    else:
        L.append(N)
        B = 1
L.pop()
print(L)
```

Prints out:

```
>>10
>>[2, 5]
```

**EDIT**

That's the problem with infinity loop, but won't give you the right answer in some cases e.g. 20 because its logic is wrong. I modified a little bit the code and this is what I have.

```
N = int(input())
B = N
L = []
while B != 1:
    for i in range(2,N):
        if N % i ==0:
            L.append(i)
            N = N // i
            break
    else:
        L.append(N)
        B = 1
print(L)
```

Comment: Ok, but if you do that the output will not be the prime factorization of the number, you can try number 20 and you will see.

Comment: @Mohamed_Elsharaky, I've just added the right logic, hope this helps you

Comment: Thank you very much for this I tried to modify the logic of the program and I figure out the I was wrong when I used the variable B, Thank you again.

Comment: You're welcome, don't forget to mark it as answer

Answer (score 0):

while B != 1: is giving you an infinite loop.  You can use a debugger and see that  when, for example, N = 9, B never goes to 1 and the script keeps appending 3 to L forever.

Answer (score 0):

You never increment i. The break statement takes you to "while b!= 1". So it appends 2 (or the first factor of N) to L infinitely.

Comment: Ok,  but I set B = N // i so that the the value of B will  be changed if the statement is true, and if the for loop ends without break the B will be changed to 1 so the while loop will be terminated.

Comment: If B isn't changed to exactly 1, it will not break out of the while loop.

Comment: I know that but can you explain it in more detail.

Comment: The answer above shows that simply do not want the break statement. The break takes you to line 4, and the for loop starts at the beginning (2) not at the next number in the sequence. Since the loop never ends, the code never reaches "else:"